# How to get the "relative position" of indices in lists?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the relative position of indices in lists. These lists are all of different length. Let's say that we have two lists:

```
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The indices of the element `3` in both lists is:

```
>>> list1.index(3)
3
>>> list2.index(3)
3
```

The "absolute positions" are both `3`, however common sense says that their relative positions would be different since each list's length is different.

What I did is simply divide both lists by their largest elements and create a dictionary mapping the original elements to the newly created relative positions.

```
>>> list1_norm = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(list1, [(x / max(list1)) for x in list1])}
>>> list2_norm = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(list2, [(x / max(list2)) for x in list2])}
>>> list1_norm
{0: 0.0,
 1: 0.1111111111111111,
 2: 0.2222222222222222,
 3: 0.3333333333333333,
 4: 0.4444444444444444,
 5: 0.5555555555555556,
 6: 0.6666666666666666,
 7: 0.7777777777777778,
 8: 0.8888888888888888,
 9: 1.0}
>>> list2_norm
{0: 0.0,
 1: 0.07142857142857142,
 2: 0.14285714285714285,
 3: 0.21428571428571427,
 4: 0.2857142857142857,
 5: 0.35714285714285715,
 6: 0.42857142857142855,
 7: 0.5,
 8: 0.5714285714285714,
 9: 0.6428571428571429,
 10: 0.7142857142857143,
 11: 0.7857142857142857,
 12: 0.8571428571428571,
 13: 0.9285714285714286,
 14: 1.0}
```

which now gives us:

```
>>> list1_norm.index(3)
```

So now we know that the position of `3` relative to the lists' lengths is `0.3333` and `0.21428` for each list.

Is there any other way that I would be able to implement the same concept without having to perform tedious list and dictionary comprehensions? Thanks.

Comment: In your code above I think `list1_norm[3]` is equivalent to `list1.index(3) / max(list1)`. But based on what you described in the question I think you want `list1.index(3) / len(list1)`. Is either of these the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Ah, yes you're correct. I had originally used `len` but I guess for this example my brain told me to write `max`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: How is my question not focused? Would be good if whoever voted to close could elaborate so I could make some edits.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the index by the length of the minus 1

```
def rel_index(l, elem):
    return l.index(elem)/(len(l) - 1)
```

Usage:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

print(rel_index(list1, 3))
print(rel_index(list2, 3))
```

Output:

```
0.3333333333333333
0.2
```

This evenly spreads/assigns the elements from 0.0 to 1.0.

If you want to evenly spread the elements from 1/n to 1.0, use the following instead

```
def rel_index(l, elem):
    return (l.index(elem) + 1)/(len(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you can avoid comprehensions and dicts entirely if you would like. You can simply create a function (or lambda if you want to keep it a one liner that implements the same logic:

```
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> rel_pos = lambda l, elem: elem / max(l)
>>> rel_pos(list1, 5)
0.5555555555555556
```

The other thing you may consider is implementing your own class with this as a method - you can implement whatever lookup methods you want in your own class. So for example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> class MyList(collections.UserList):
...     def rel_pos(self, elem):
...         return elem / max(self)
...
>>> my_list1 = MyList(list1)
>>> my_list1.rel_pos(5)
0.5555555555555556
```

Neither of these solutions may present the exact same behavior that you would like, but you are free to implement this to fit your need.